# How does a bluetooth earphone receive and play a song at the same time? Multi threading?

Tags: multithreading, bluetooth

I'm guessing the bluetooth earphone has a buffer to hold bytes from the song. This means that it will receive and play the song at the same time. How is this done? Something as small as a bluetooth earphone can't have multi threading can it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typical bluetooth earphones have processors that are as powerful as the ones that powered cellphones just a few years ago. Samsung's newest bluetooth headphones use a 32-bit Arm Cortex M3 CPU, similar to the processors used in smartphones just a few years ago.

Comment: Which headphones are you referring to? Is this also true for truly wireless earphones like the apple airpods?

Comment: Many current models including Samsung's. Apple's Airpods have an even more sophisticated processor designed specifically by Apple. Even the H1 processor could recognize "Hey, Siri!" right on the 'pods.